# Parametrising Scala trait

Tags: scala, traits

*Disclaimer: This question is not about whether I should do it or whether it is a good design nor any related reasoning. The question is about how I can do it. Me explaining why later on is just for clarification.*

---

Can I parametrise a Scala trait? I know they can't have constructor parameters - is there a different way? For something like (this is only an example, of course)

```
case class MyMachine(myDouble: Double) {
    def methodEveryMachineHas(): Double = 2 * myDouble
}

trait Drivable {
    this: MyMachine =>

    def drive(x: Double): Double = HowToDriveFunction(x) * myDouble

}

object HowToDriveFunction extends (Double => Double) {
    def apply(x:Double): Double = x + 6.0
}

val myMachine1 = new MyMachine(3.0)
myMachine1.methodEveryMachineHas // 6.0
myMachine1.drive(4.0) // error

val myMachine2 = new MyMachine(3.0) with Drivable
myClass1.methodEveryMachineHas // 6.0
myClass1.drive(4.0) // 30.0 = (4.0 + 6.0) * 3.0
```

How do I pass `HowToDriveFunction` to `drive`?

### Why I want this

#### Representing logically different things as programmatic different things, making for code that makes sense

The Function is supposed to be fixed anchored in the object (= instantiated class) itself. Thus I want it to be given during creation. However not all `MyMachine`s are supposed to have the drive ability.

Imagine `MyMachine` to be a machine, and `Drivable` to say it's driveable - if something can not drive by logic, I think it should also not be technically be able to drive, thus the trait. But I still need to explain (via `HowToDriveFunction`) how the driving works for this particular machine (which might be a car or a plane). However, why should I be able to explain every machine how to drive? That makes no sense. I only want to be able to explain it to those that can drive at all. Thus I want to give `HowToDriveFunction` to the trait (which says the machine can drive and thus should be able to drive in the first place). *How* the driving works is not a ability (= trait), but a description of the mechanics and should be represented by a Function in my opinion. If it is logically different, it would be nice if that was represented by a different programming construct.

Of course, my actual stuff has nothing to do with machines and such - it's just an example.

If my function was given via another trait, I could write

```
trait HowToDriveFunction {
    this: Drivable =>
    ???
}
```

to make sure that only those that are `Drivable` get a subclass of `HowToDriveFunction`, but this does not seem so beautiful to me, for reasons explained.

#### Following "composition over inheritance"

Last but not least I think it good to have [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) because I feel that it makes it easier to reason about code.

Comment: What about using a function: `def calculate(f: Double => Double)(x: Double): Double = f(x)`. Is there a particular reason why you want to use a class and `object` that extends `Double => Double`?

Comment: "I don't want to ..." is rarely a sound basis for a technical decision ...

Comment: Note that dotty (platform to try out new language concepts and compiler technologies for Scala ) has them: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/640

Comment: @Dima: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: @Make42: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_engineering

Comment: @Dima: I see your point... https://i.imgflip.com/1c3q18.jpg :-D Well played... Seriously though: You asked why I didn't want to inherit via another trait. I think my answer is legit, isn't it? My answer was that I wanted to follow the mentioned design principle, which - I think - leads to more readable code. A more lengthy explanation for this particular case was already given by me in my last edit of the question.

Comment: Extend the class then.

To be clear: I don't think that there is anything particularly "legit" about wanting to "follow a design principle" as such, without an actual reason. 
Inheritance is as much a "design principle" as composition. So, saying "I don't want to use inheritance" isn't any more or less "legit" then "I want to follow the design principle of composition".
If a machine doesn't know how to drive, it's not much of a machine, is it?

Comment: I for one see no reason to think of doubling as "an ability" and of adding a 6 as a "description of mechanics".  The "logical difference" you are referring to still escapes me.

Comment: @Dima: :-D Sure it's a machine. For example a jackhammer does not drive... since when is a machine defined by it's ability to drive... I am not sure what you mean by "Extend the class then". Isn't that the same as inheritance? The doubling etc. is an example (as I wrote). I think that is obvious, why are you giving me a hard time?

Comment: That's exactly why it should be a separate trait. Some machines are `Drivable`, others are not. Composition doesn't make any sense in this context.

Comment: @Dima: That is already what I am doing. Please review my question again. Edited it again.

Comment: I think, this is an opinion-based question. It doesn't really belong on SO.
You seem to see some kind of a distinction between an ability and a behavior ... To me, those things are synonymous.

As to the "composition over inheritance", that's largely a java concept, born from the lack of multiple inheritance. It doesn't really apply to scala that much.

Comment: @Dima: You misunderstand the question: I am not asking whether I should do what I want to do it. This is a discussion you forced on me with "this is not a valid reason for a technical decision". But I my question was not whether it is a valid reasoning. I am just asking how to do what I want to do it. That is a question for SO.

Comment: without reading all the comments, a question: what's wrong with just passing the function to drive()? e.g. `def drive(x: Double, f: Double => Double): Double = f(x) * myDouble`

Comment: @slouc: No need to read the comments: I put it in the question by now: "The Function is supposed to be fixed anchored in the object (= instantiated class) itself. Thus I want it to be given during creation."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but it seems to boil down to

> How do I pass `HowToDriveFunction` to `drive`?

And to be able to define `MyMachine` without being drivable.

For this you simply need to define an abstract member in `Drivable`.

```
case class MyMachine(myDouble: Double) {
  def methodEveryMachineHas: Double = 2 * myDouble
}

trait Drivable {
  this: MyMachine =>

  protected def driveFunction: Double => Double

  def drive(x: Double): Double = driveFunction(x) * myDouble
}

object HowToDriveFunction extends (Double => Double) {
  def apply(x: Double): Double = x + 6.0
}

val myMachine1 = new MyMachine(3.0)
myMachine1.methodEveryMachineHas // 6.0
myMachine1.drive(4.0) // error

val myMachine2 = new MyMachine(3.0) with Drivable { 
  val driveFunction = HowToDriveFunction
}
myMachine2.methodEveryMachineHas // 6.0
myMachine2.drive(4.0) // 30.0 = (4.0 + 6.0) * 3.0
```

Comment: That's what I am talking about. Thanks. One question though: Are the `{...}` making a class or object out of the trait, initialising it with `val driveFunction`?

Comment: It's just an anonymous sub-class of `MyMachine with Drivable` (implementing the abstract method). You could also write `object MyDrivableMachine extends MyMachine(3) with Drivable { val driveFunction = ... }`.